# 4,000 questions reached!

Tags: discussion

Glanced over at the statistics and noticed the landmark (well, technically 4,002).  Based on posting times, it looks like [In the japanese The legend of Zelda (e.g. Ocarina of Time), why is navi spelled ナビィ and not just ナビ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15114/in-the-japanese-the-legend-of-zelda-e-g-ocarina-of-time-why-is-navi-spelled) gets the honor.  Figured people might like to know.

**[Edit:** I thought questions could be designated as CW...guess not?**]**

Comment: Moderators can mark questions as CW.  If you think a question should be CW, you can flag it and explain why.  (These days not many questions need to be CW, though.)